# Shopify product API integer limit 4

Tags: api, shopify

I am getting the error

```
3401314564 is out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 4
```

when updating a product via the Shopify API. The integer here is one of Shopify's own, so it should be in range. Is there a data type problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You need to use long integer format. Limit of 8 will help you when you setup this field in PostgreSQL.

Shopify has a warning about this from two years ago, but only now is it really kicking in...

Comment: Interesting, and thanks. Do you have a link to their heads-up? I can't find one.

Comment: Here is the link from May 2013:

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/partners-technical/t/major-change-shopify-is-growing-and-so-are-our-ints-141045